# R: Object type 'closure' not subsettable

Tags: r

I was trying to fill rows of a matrix using the sample function, but got an error saying Object type 'closure' is not subsettable. Where have I gone wrong? I referred to questions with similar titles, but none of them helped.

My code

```
my_matrix <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 1)
my_info = c(0, 1)
my_prob = c(0.5, 0.5)
for(i in 1:10){
  matrix[i,] <- sample(my_info, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = my_prob)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix[i,]` should be `my_matrix[i,]`. `matrix` is a function, not a variable, so you get an error saying that it is not subsettable.